# A doubt about the classic problem of measuring the speed of light in only one direction

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Why can't two clocks synchronized with signals SLOWER than the speed of light, measure the speed of light in one direction?

I know that it is not possible to measure the speed of light in only one direction, and I understand why two clocks synchronized with light signals are useless.  But I realize that I can't explain why two clocks synchronized with signals slower than light don't work either.

Comment: What method of "slower than light" could we use?

Comment: Lets suppose that I am between the two clocks, at the same distance from each other, and I throw two baseballs at the same time, at the same speed, each one towards each clock, which triggers them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because neither the speed of light, nor the speed of a turtle in one direction can be measured without arbitrary assumptions about the synchronism of clocks at the point of departure and point of arrival.

Comment: Thanks Albert.  That makes sense, of course ... I had not thought of it that way.  I'm thinking that if instead of worrying about launching my signals at the same speed, I do it with the same kinetic energy, I'll have the same problem, right?